# React: [name] is not detected

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple list where I'm trying to update multiple inputs.

In console, `(name)` returns nothing. I added `name` in both inputs as mentionned in the [official react docs for multiple input handling](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

**How do I manage to return value for each input `(title, description)`?**

```js
const F = () => {

  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "a",
      title: "Random title 1",
      description: "Random description 1"
    },
    {
      id: "b",
      title: "Random title 2",
      description: "Random description 2"
    },
    {
      id: "c",
      title: "Random title 3",
      description: "Random description 3"
    },
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);
  const [title, setTitle] = React.useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = React.useState("");

  function handleChangeUpdate(id, value) {
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const updatedItem = {
            ...item,
            name: value
          };
   
        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });
 
    setList(newList);
    console.log(newList);
    console.log(name); 
    console.log(id);
  }
 
  return (
    <div>                
        <ul >             
            <div>
                {list.map((item) => (                                                                    
                    <li key={item.id}>                      
                    <input name="title" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, e.target.title)} defaultValue={item.name}></input>
                    <input name="description" className="form-control" onChange={(e)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, e.target.description)} defaultValue={item.description}></input>
                    </li>
                    ))}                   
            </div>               
        </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<F />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I think the lack of expected behavior might be because you are using `e.target.description` and `e.target.title` instead of `e.target.value`, when calling `handleChangeUpdate(...)` within the `onChange`

Comment: @RamizWachtler I just tried what you suggested, and the problem is the same value is updated for both `title` and `description`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`name` isn't defined anywhere in the handler so that is why it is undefined. If I had to guess it seems you meant to use the entire event object in the handler to access the input name and value.

There was also a typo in the inputs where you had `defaultValue={item.name}` for the title input, but it should be `defaultValue={item.title}`.

```
function handleChangeUpdate(id, event) {
  const { name, value} = event.target; // <-- access input name & value
  const newList = list.map((item) => {
    if (item.id === id) {
      const updatedItem = {
        ...item,
       [name]: value // <-- name is dynamic key for value
      };

      return updatedItem;
    }
    return item;
  });

  setList(newList);
  console.log(newList);
  console.log(id);
}

...

<input
  name="title"
  className="form-control"
  onChange={(event)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, event)} // <-- pass entire event
  defaultValue={item.title}
/>
<input
  name="description"
  className="form-control"
  onChange={(event)=> handleChangeUpdate(item.id, event)}
  defaultValue={item.description}
/>
```

```js
const F = () => {
  const initialList = [
    {
      id: "a",
      title: "Random title 1",
      description: "Random description 1"
    },
    {
      id: "b",
      title: "Random title 2",
      description: "Random description 2"
    },
    {
      id: "c",
      title: "Random title 3",
      description: "Random description 3"
    }
  ];

  const [list, setList] = React.useState(initialList);

  function handleChangeUpdate(id, event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const newList = list.map((item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        const updatedItem = {
          ...item,
          [name]: value
        };

        return updatedItem;
      }
      return item;
    });

    setList(newList);
    console.log(newList);
    console.log(id);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        <div>
          {list.map((item) => (
            <li key={item.id}>
              <input
                name="title"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(e) => handleChangeUpdate(item.id, e)}
                defaultValue={item.title}
              ></input>
              <input
                name="description"
                className="form-control"
                onChange={(e) => handleChangeUpdate(item.id, e)}
                defaultValue={item.description}
              ></input>
            </li>
          ))}
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <F />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: @AlyaKra You had a `defaultValue={item.name}`, but it should be `defaultValue={item.title}`. I updated my answer and added a stack snippet.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment as I want posting exactly the same thing. Thank you very very much man. As a beginner in react I tried everything for a whole day and nothing. Even React official documentation didn't help me much. Thanks again !